# How do you convert text like `'$71.4145` into a number you can do arithmetic with

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The title says it all. One thing I want to avoid is long formulas. If it's more than a single function, something is clearly wrong since this should be a common use case.

I've tried `TO_PURE_NUMBER` and `VALUE`

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that the value `$71.4145` is not a number but a text string. That can happen if your spreadsheet locale is such that it expects comma as decimal mark, or expects a different currency symbol. It will also happen if you have formatted the value as plain text rather than currency.

To convert the text string `$71.4145` into the number 71.4145 (seventy-one and change), use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=iferror( value( regexextract( to_text(A2), "[\d.]+" ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--` to suppress text to equivalent number values. Try-

```
=--A1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; "$"; )*1
```